# Hidden Files Not Being Copied On Mac with cp -r

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, copy

Very very weird issue. I have a project that has hidden files on Mac OS 12.2.1, I am try to copy over. For example:

```
drwxr-xr-x   16 john  staff      512 Jun 25 10:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 john  staff      192 Jun 27 06:50 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 john  staff     6148 Jun  5 13:52 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   14 john  staff      448 Jun 26 20:29 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff      310 Jun  4 09:52 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff      368 Jun  4 10:15 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff     3486 Jun 20 15:29 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    8 john  staff      256 Jun 24 16:49 build
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff      217 Jun  4 10:16 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  817 john  staff    26144 Jun 25 14:31 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff  1075501 Jun 25 14:31 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff     1185 Jun 25 14:31 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff       82 Jun  4 10:30 postcss.config.js
drwxr-xr-x    9 john  staff      288 Jun  5 14:00 public
drwxr-xr-x   18 john  staff      576 Jun 20 13:42 src
-rw-r--r--    1 john  staff     2836 Jun  5 02:36 tailwind.config.js
```

Now I run the following command

```
sudo cp -R * ../otherfolder
```

And I've also tried a variation

```
cp -r * ../otherfolder
```

And the following is there:

```
drwxr-xr-x   13 john  staff      416 Jun 27 07:54 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 john  staff      192 Jun 27 06:50 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff      368 Jun 27 07:54 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff     3486 Jun 27 07:54 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    8 john        staff      256 Jun 27 07:54 build
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff      217 Jun 27 07:54 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  817 john        staff    26144 Jun 27 07:54 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff  1075501 Jun 27 07:54 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff     1185 Jun 27 07:54 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff       82 Jun 27 07:54 postcss.config.js
drwxr-xr-x    9 john        staff      288 Jun 27 07:54 public
drwxr-xr-x   18 john        staff      576 Jun 27 07:54 src
-rw-r--r--    1 john        staff     2836 Jun 27 07:54 tailwind.config.js
```

None of the invisible files with a period in front have NOT been copied over. Any ideas?

Comment: `*` is expanded by the shell before it's passed to the `cp` command, and the shell doesn't include invisible files when it does that (which is a good thing, or it'd include `..`, which you *don't* want to copy).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The problem is the zsh in MacOS, as I learned in another post.
"*" does not select hidden files in zsh.

The correct command to recursively copy on zsh including hidden files is:
cp -r *(D) ../otherfolder

Answer (score -1):

```
cp -rpv . /path/to/other/folder/
```

Comment: This command is doing exactly what the person was asking for. copying a content of a folder (in this case the same folder he is in) to other folder including the hidden files which begin a dot in it's name.

Comment: Does not work on Mac command line. Hidden files are still not copied.

Comment: @Michael - this is working on MacOS command line and tested as working just now to double check,.